# Typhoon module dependencies resolved to TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy

Tags: objective-c, dependency-injection, typhoon

I'm trying to integrate Typhoon Framework into my app and stuck with one problem.

I have 3 classes that inherited from `TyphoonAssembly`. One of them depends on another one.

Here is a code of the assembly that has dependency

```
@interface SMObjectFactory : TyphoonAssembly

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) SMManagersAssembly *managersAssembly;

- (SMNote *)createEmptyNoteWithCurrentDate;

@end

// ===================================

@implementation SMObjectFactory {}

- (SMNote *)createEmptyNoteWithCurrentDate {
    return [TyphoonDefinition withClass:[SMNote class] configuration:^(TyphoonDefinition *definition) {
        [definition useInitializer:@selector(init)];
        NSDate *dateAdded = [NSDate date];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(key) with:[NSString UUID1WithDate:dateAdded]];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(dateAdded) with:dateAdded];
        [definition injectProperty:@selector(folderKey) with:self.managersAssembly.folderManager.defaultFolder];
    }];
}

@end
```

The problem occurs when calling `self.managersAssembly.folderManager.defaultFolder`. Here is `self.managersAssembly` is an instance of `TyphoonCollaboratingAssemblyProxy`, hence, `self.managersAssembly.highlightManager` is instance of TyphoonReferenceDefinition instead of actual assembly and object that should be returned by folderManager respectively.

Assemblies defined in Info.plist as following

[image: Assemblies defined in Info.plist as following]

I tried to change ordering of these items, no luck.

Without the `self.managersAssembly.folderManager.defaultFolder` line it compiles successfully and if, for example, in app delegate class (which is also injected) I call [(SMManagersAssembly *)self.assembly highlightManager].defaultHighlight it works perfectly well.

What I'm doing wrong and what is the propper way of doing it?

Typhoon 2.2.1

Answer (score 1):

To do what you would like please refer to ['Injecting Objects Produced by Other Components'](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon/wiki/Types-of-Injections#injecting-objects-produced-by-other-components) in the User Guide, which outlines two styles of doing essentially the same thing. Use the one that is most applicable.

Also note that:

You create one or more assemblies. In the latter case components in one assembly can refer to components in another, by declaring a property. For example:

```
@interface PFApplicationAssembly : TyphoonAssembly

@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) PFCoreComponents *coreComponents;
@property(nonatomic, strong, readonly) PFThemeAssembly *themeProvider;

@end
```

Typhoon will build your application with any combination of assemblies that fulfill the above, eg {PFApplicationAssembly, TestCoreComponents, ColorfulThemes}

You should only override an assembly if you wish to override a definition (eg test vs production), otherwise components can just refer to each other as shown above.